# Does SQL Server 2005 Express default to TCP port 1433?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am looking in SQL Server Configuration Manager, 'Protocols for SQLEXPRESS'

And IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4, and IPALL have the TCP Port blank.

Should that be 1433 or it will default to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a specific port like 1433, you have to set it manually.

The default instance will use port **1433** by default, if TCP is enabled and the settings are left unchanged. A named instance will use a dynamic port by default. So the question really boils down to whether the Express instance is named or default (assuming the port number in the OP is a typo).

**Update**

If the Configuration Manager says 'Protocols for SQLEXPRESS' it means the Express instance is a named one so it will use dynamic ports by default. You have to change the settings to use port 1433.
.

Comment: how can I tell if its a named instance?  .\SQLExpress works when logging in locally.

Comment: It's a named instance and it's name is SQLEXPRESS. You would connect to a default instance using `.` alone or `local` or `localhost`. When you connect to it locally you connect using shared-memory and the TCP listennitng port is irelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get SQL Express to accept remote connections, it does not do this by default.  You must enable this feature.  Here is the KB for doing so.  [KB914277](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

Comment: thanks I read and did all that.  server doesn't have windows firewall running (external firewall).

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Express instances will use dynamic ports so the SQL Browser service is there to help clients connect.  You can set a static port if you wish in SQL Configuration Manager.